# how to let autoconf select the expected license template instead GPL v3 as default?

Tags: autoconf, automake

I use autoconf to generate project building files. I don't add COPYING file by manual and autoconf will generate a COPYING file using GPL v3 license.

My question is, is there any way to instruct autoconf to generate an expected license template like LGPL, such as passing an option, etc?

Answer (score 1):

Normally, since you are not using GPL, you would specify 'foreign' in AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE and include your own copying file.  You can certainly have your bootstrap script copy the template in for you.  Or, a reasonable solution is simply replace automake's template.  Just copy your license into Automake's pkgvdatadir.  (eg, $HOME/share/automake-1.11/COPYING).

Answer (score 0):

Thats a good question (I guess you want to put a minimum amount of files under version control and want to generate all necessary files with autoreconf?). However I do not think it is possible, because the automake (which is responsible for creating this file) manual states in Chapter 21 -- The effect of --gnu and --gnits:

> The files INSTALL, NEWS, README, AUTHORS, and ChangeLog, plus one of COPYING.LIB, COPYING.LESSER or COPYING, are required at the topmost directory of the package.
>
> If the --add-missing option is given, automake will add a generic version of the INSTALL file as well as the COPYING file containing the text of the current version of the GNU General Public License existing at the time of this Automake release (version 3 as this is written, http://www.gnu.org/copyleft/gpl.html). However, an existing COPYING file will never be overwritten by automake.